# Question closed as opinion based, that is unusual but clearly not opinion based

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question, closed-questions

The question in consideration is [Actual eletronic games (as in, games played using electrons)?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/535818/)

I understand that this question is different from other questions on this site, but I think it can be objectively answered. Not in the sense of a complete answer, but surely we could comply a list of fun ways we can interact with electrons, that could be used as games.

I think such games can be very educational and would be a nice way to transport some physics to a younger audience (~8th grade pupil). Games are an excellent way to get kids excited about doing experiments.

So I think this question shouldn't have been closed in the first place. I would like to hear in which sense the particular question is opinion based and why it is not appreciated.

Comment: "......but surely we could comply a **list** of fun......" if this is so then the question comes into [tag:big-list] category.

Comment: @JohanLiebert The questions in the catgeory are mostly low quality, I agree. But this one is quite creative. I think we shouldn't always be that bureaucratic.

Comment: @TheoreticalMinimum Stack Exchange questions are supposed to solicit a small number of focused answers. List questions don't work so well with this format because they attract a virtually endless stream of answers, and it can be difficult to evaluate those answers in a non-opinionated way.

Answer (score 5):

I was one of the close voters. The reason I voted to close is because it isn't a question about physics. That doesn't mean it's a bad or uninteresting question, it just means it isn't an appropriate question for the Physics SE. I still think this and will probably vote to close again if the question is reopened.

I should probably have taken the time to write a custom close reason, but the close queue is getting large enough to be onerous these days and the time I have to work through it is limited.

Comment: The majority seems to agree with you, so I will not further push my opinion on the matter.